# kubernetes: external IP (of LB) needed in argo events SNS source

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-sns, argo, argo-events

I'm using argo-events in kubernetes and setting up an Event Source which will receive an SNS message.

In the YAML for this event source, I need to set the 'endpoint' so the SNS service can call my event source.  For this I'm setting up a Load Balancer, so its gets an external IP, and I setup the Load Balancer to forward calls to my Event Source's pod.

Problem is: I need to first setup the Load Balancer, then get its external IP, then modify the Event Source YAML and deploy it.  I'd like to be able to always deploy the same YAML, and do something like 'using a variable' in the Event Source's YAML set to the external IP of the load balancer.

Is this (or something equivalent) possible?

Note 1(if it matters): My kubernetes cluster is not running on AWS
Note 2: Eventually I'd like to use Argo CD, so any tool which would modify the Event Source's YAML would see that config changed (unless that tool writes it to github I guess?)